# Cannot ssh to machin using local address but can access its external ip address

Tags: ssh

My centOS target machine has two network cards. nic0 is connected to a modem: I can ssh from Raspberry Pi4 to the centOS target using the external address of the modem (with the help of port forwarding on the modem.)

nic1 is connected to my local network. But when I try to ssh using the local address I get a timeout, like this:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.8.2 [192.168.8.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
```

ssh to local address has been working fine for many months - just suddenly stopped working. I looked the `/var/log/secure` and did not see any activity when tring to ssh to the local address. I am not aware of any recent system changes to the target machine.

Any ideas?